# Bootstrap 4 image position

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have a problem with **Bootstrap 4**. Left box does not align with a right box. There is a **HTML** and **CSS**. How can I solve this problem?

```
<section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">Section Title</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="left-box">
                <img src="images/category-1.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="left-box">
                <img src="images/category-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="right-box">
                <img src="images/category-3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-box{ position:relative; padding-top:30px;}
.right-box{position:relative; padding-top:30px;}
```

[image: Screenshot browser][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FzfP.gif)

Thank you.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses flex so you can stretch divs and items to align using these classes `d-flex align-items-stretch` - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/ - how ever since the left is longer it will probably stretch the right side to align with the left, based on your image

Comment: I solved using the bootstrap 4 cards. - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/ -

Answer (score 0):

There is two kind of [Container in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#overview-container), in your case `container-fluid` is more adapted.
Change `container` to `container-fluid`

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work.